# Returning list in for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Forgive what is likely an elementary question, but I'm struggling to parse a .csv file into a list. Within the "For" loop, I get the full list of items I want, but outside of it, it only returns the last iterated row.

'''

```
for i in subset.index:
    alta = pd.DataFrame()
    transactions = []
    transactions.append(subset['Date'][i])
    transactions.append(subset['Credit Amount'][i])
    transactions.append(subset['Debit Amount'][i])
    transactions.append(subset['Description'][i])
    print(transactions)
```

'''

This returns the below:

'''

```
['9/28/2018', nan, 46494533.33, 'SWEEP TO TREAS REPO I']
['9/28/2018', 46521123.39, nan, 'Invest-SWEEP TREASURY REPO - ICBC']
['9/28/2018', nan, 26590.06, 'SENDER BNK:=SIL VLY BK SCLA; SENDER ID:=121140399; SENDER REF:=20172799961800; ORG ID:=3300000000; ORG:=HL ADVISORS; ORG ADDRESS:=PO BOX 1 NEW YORK']
['9/28/2018', 10150015.1, nan, 'SENDER BNK:=SIL VLY BK SCLA; SENDER ID:=121140399; SENDER REF:=201809280156999; ORG ID:=3300000000; ORG:=WB ADVISORS; ORG ADDRESS:=PO BOX 1 NEW YORK']
['9/28/2018', nan, 35.0, nan]
['9/28/2018', nan, 670000.0, nan]
```

'''

When I run 'print(transactions" out side the "For" loop, I only get the below:

**['9/28/2018', nan, 670000.0, nan]**

Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: On the third line, you're overwriting the "transactions" variable with a new list during every iteration of the loop. Create the list before the loop.

Comment: You aren't *returning* anything; you are writing a string representation of the *current* transaction to standard output in each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Each *transactions* list corresponds to one iteration (because you initialize it inside the loop). At the end, you'll have the results of the last iteration. To keep track of all of them, you need to append each *transactions* list, into a "global transactions list", defined outside of the loop.

```py
transactions_list = []
for i in subset.index:
    transactions = []
    # ...
    transactions_list.append(transactions)

print(transactions_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, CristiFati. Your guidance is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that your `transactions=[]` list is inside the for loop, it is being overwritten each time you loop through it.

```py
transactions=[]
for item in items:
    list_item = "something"
    transactions.append(list_item)
```

These kind of learning questions are better suited for pythondev.slack.com to help you get on your feet.

Comment: This is wrong. why use `_`? and you should not use `iter` for naming variables.

Comment: edited. the point in _ was to keep the focus on the subject at hand